# My electric lawn mower won't start after getting grass blocking the blade

Tags: lawn-mower

I haven't mowed for many months due to special circumstances so my yard's grass was pretty dense. Several time the motor stopped after grass formed a compact bulk completely blocking the blade. After the third time this happened, my [Flymo Easimo Electric Wheeled Lawn Mower](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0014BKQT4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)(Amazon link) doesn't start any more.

What is the likely cause and can I do something about it? I really don't feel like buying another one right now.

EDIT:
There was no smell when opening the bonnet, and no disconnected wire or anything like that. Also I used the lowest setting (meaning the one to cut the grass as short as possible)

EDIT #2:
I just tried again and the mower now works! Yet for 5 minutes trying an hour ago, nothing.

Comment: Was there any sort of burning smell when the mower stopped? Have you tried removing any of the plastic work to see if there are any loose/opened connections or any indication of melted wiring or other damage to the motor itself? If so, post pics of the damage.

Comment: When cutting very high grass it is prudent to set the mower on the highest level, and even cut half strips by overlapping the courses. Then in a few days mow again at the desired level.

Comment: Additional tall grass cutting tip: you can also push forward, then push the handle _down_ causing the mower to rise. This will allow it to spray grass everywhere, not just out the chute, and will help clear it. You may have to go a 1/2 mower length at a time, depending on how long the grass is... You may have to rake after this, but you shouldn't have to do this more than 1x per year, right?

Comment: Also, from the "it never hurts to check the obvious" department: Is there any damage to the power cord? Is the cord is still plugged in. Did the circuit breaker trip?

Comment: If no smell then you may have blown a safety fuse somewhere in the machine.  Consult the owners manual.  However, if you check/replace the fuse, and it still won't start, then the motor is likely burned out.  "*When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.*" ~Sir Arthur Conan Doyle

Comment: Had another thought.  Electric mowers tend to be high speed, low torque spinners.  Meaning: a residual obstruction may prevent the blade from spinning when starting up.  Make sure your mower is unplugged (and battery removed, if any), overturn the machine, and carefully inspect in blade housing, especially around the shaft, for any remaining debris that might obstruct the blade (even a little) from turning.  Carefully remove the debris, upright the mower, and finally attempt another start.

Comment: Thank you all for your useful input! @isherwood the mower now works! I tried for 5 minutes an hour ago to no avail, I suppose thermal overload protection is the right explanation.

Comment: Yes, probably thermal protection.  And adding emphasis to what others have said here...when mowing tall grass, you want to mow it as tall as possible, otherwise it "shocks" the grass and it will have a harder time recovering. Taking a smaller bite (1/2 row at a time is easier on the mower. I assume you're not bagging, if correct, be sure to blow the clippings over the cut grass, not over the uncut grass to further minimize the load on the mower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have tripped a thermal overload protection and just need to let things cool down, or there may be a manual reset. Batteries and electric motors are fairly dense structures and may take a while to cool down. Place the mower in a breezy location or put a fan on it to speed the process.

Obviously to prevent this you'd want to reduce the load on the machine. Take narrower swaths or raise the deck, and move slowly.

Answer (score 3):

I've cut through meter-high grasses and other stuff with a plain lawnmower.  The trick is, you need to go very, very, **very** slowly.  And listen closely to the machine, it will make detectable noises when it is starting to overload and you must detect and respond swiftly to stop that.

Also, this is a time you'll want those blades super sharp.  So if you have the means, keep em bright!

It's gonna take an age, compared to what you're used to.  You won't like that.  But don't think about how miserable the job is *today*, think of the *dozen times* this year you *didn't* have to do it.  It's a huge net savings, so you should be happy.

Answer (score -1):

**$18 dollar solution: swing blade**

[source](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ames-Double-Blade-Weed-Cutter-2915300/204476217?mtc=Shopping-B-F_D28I-G-D28I-28_11_TOOLS-MULTI-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-BASE_SHP&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D28I-G-D28I-28_11_TOOLS-MULTI-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-BASE_SHP-71700000048356161-58700004807804240-92700041230805223&gclid=EAIaIQobChMInb3a_PzU6gIVE9bACh2aDwkMEAQYASABEgKZOPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

[image]

I have been having lots of fun with my new swing blade this summer.  You can take the blade off and sharpen it up super sharp.  It goes thru grass and weeds like they were nothing.  If you hit one of the rocks that make the lot unsafe for the mower it will kick up sparks!  Sparks show up better if you go out in the dead of night, when it is cool.  With this you will not wake up your neighbors doing your lawn in the dead of night.

Wear gloves, starting when you sharpen it.

You can plow thru all that tall grass with your swing blade and then use Buzzy the Electric Mower to keep it short.

Or maybe stick to the swing blade.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about getting an electric mower to work again.

Comment: @isherwood:  /can I do something about it? /. No constraints given on what that action might be.

Comment: Interesting tool, unfortunately they don't sell anything like that here in the UK!

Comment: @drake035 - in the UK you can get a proper scythe.